# Remote Action Failed . 0x80073CF6

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, uwp, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-universal

How to solve this error in deploy side load application UWP?
[image]

Comment: So you are trying to deploy the app to phone device right? I remember there was a known issue that can be solved by rebooting the phone. If it cannot work, try to describe the detailed steps you used. And does it work for a blank app?

Comment: @AlanYao-MSFT : yes right. I try to rebooting the phone, but it can't work only for this app. And works well for other applications.
The detail steps that I use like this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt203806.aspx) from microsoft. 
I've installed this application before, and I uninstall it. and then when I install again I got error like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem solved by Update Visual Studio 2015 to Visual Studio 2015 Update 1.
Run again from console and i get different error message like this :
[image]

And then I have a package that makes error. 
So I unintsall that like this : [image]

Install that package again and it working well.. :D